# How to add numbers automatically by entering

Tags: javascript

I have a form which has many fields. In these fields there are payment fields starting from payment1 to payment12. Whenever values are input into these fields it should perform an addition of all the values automatically. At times the user might enter few fields or may be all of them.

The problem is that until i input values to all the fields i do not get an sum
Below is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('../../Admin Panel/db.php');

$remoteemployeeid = $_GET['RemoteEmployeeID'];

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4, #datepicker5, #datepicker6, #datepicker7, #datepicker8, #datepicker9, #datepicker10, #datepicker11, #datepicker12").datepicker();
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function transaction() 
{
    var AmountEarned      = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.AmountEarned.value);
    var taxdeduction      = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.taxdeduction.value);
    var TotalReceivedToDate = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.TotalReceivedToDate.value);
    var amountremainwithoffice = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.amountremainwithoffice.value);


    var PaymentsReceived1 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived1.value);
    var PaymentsReceived2 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived2.value);
    var PaymentsReceived3 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived3.value);
    var PaymentsReceived4 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived4.value);
    var PaymentsReceived5 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived5.value);
    var PaymentsReceived6 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived6.value);
    var PaymentsReceived7 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived7.value);
    var PaymentsReceived8 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived8.value);
    var PaymentsReceived9 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived9.value);
    var PaymentsReceived10 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived10.value);
    var PaymentsReceived11 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived11.value);
    var PaymentsReceived12 = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived12.value);


    var result = (AmountEarned * taxdeduction) / 100;
    var result1 = AmountEarned-result;       
    var result2 = (PaymentsReceived1 + PaymentsReceived2 + PaymentsReceived3 + PaymentsReceived4 + PaymentsReceived5 + PaymentsReceived6 + PaymentsReceived7 + PaymentsReceived8 + PaymentsReceived9 + PaymentsReceived10 + PaymentsReceived11) + PaymentsReceived12;

    var result3 = (TotalReceivedToDate - result2);    


    document.TransactionForm.tax.value = result;
    document.TransactionForm.TotalEarnAfterTax.value = result1;
    document.TransactionForm.TotalReceivedToDate.value = result2;
    document.TransactionForm.amountremainwithoffice.value = result3;


}

</script>
<style>

    table {
    border-top:1px solid #e5eff8;
    border-right:1px solid #e5eff8;
    border-left:1px solid #e5eff8;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e5eff8;
    margin:1em auto;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family:"verdana";
    }
    td {
    color:#678197;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e5eff8;
     border-top:1px solid #e5eff8;
    border-left:1px solid #e5eff8;
    }

body,td,th {
    color: #000000;
}
</style>
    <title>Remote Employee Detailed Information</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Remote Employee Transaction History_exe.php?RemoteEmployeeID=<?php echo $remoteemployeeid ?>" name="TransactionForm" method="post">   
<table width="789" height="966" border="0" cellpadding="3" style="font-family:Verdana; margin-top:30px;" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td height="99" colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" >

      <p><font size="+3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Remote Employee Transaction History </font></p>

      </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="35%" >Amount Earned:</td>
    <td width="65%" ><input type="number" id="AmountEarned" name="AmountEarned" onChange="transaction()" required ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Tax Deduction:</td>
    <td ><select name="taxdeduction" id="taxdeduction" onChange="transaction()" required="required" style="width:153px;" ><br />
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tax Deduction</option>
<option value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Two Percent</option>
<option value="7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Seven Percent</option>
<option value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ten Percent</option>

</select></td>
    </tr>
  <tr >
    <td >Deducted Tax Amount:</td>
    <td ><input size="3" readonly type="nubmer" id="tax" name="tax" style="text-align:center;" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border-bottom:6px #FFFFFF solid;">
    <td > Total Earned After Tax:</td>
    <td ><input type="number" id="TotalEarnAfterTax" name="TotalEarnAfterTax" required >
      &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" ><h3>Processed Records</h3></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Property ID:</td>
    <td ><textarea cols="35" rows="6" name="propertyID"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" ><h3>Payments Received</h3></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td >Payment 1: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Date1" type="date" id="datepicker1"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived1" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 2: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date2" id="datepicker2"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived2" onChange="transaction()"  ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 3: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date3" id="datepicker3"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived3" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 4: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date4" id="datepicker4"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived4" onChange="transaction()"  ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 5: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date5" id="datepicker5"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived5" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 6: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date6" id="datepicker6"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived6" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 7: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date7" id="datepicker7"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived7" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 8: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date8" id="datepicker8"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived8" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 9: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date9" id="datepicker9"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived9" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 10: &nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date10" id="datepicker10"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived10" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Payment 11: &nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date11" id="datepicker11"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived11" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="border-bottom:6px #FFFFFF solid;">
    <td >Payment 12: &nbsp;<input type="date" name="Date12" id="datepicker12"></td>
    <td ><input type="number" name="PaymentsReceived12" onChange="transaction()" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Total Received To Date:</td>
    <td ><input type="text" id="TotalReceivedToDate" name="TotalReceivedToDate" required onChange="transaction()" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Remaining Amount With Office:</td>
    <td ><input type="number" id="amountremainwithoffice" name="amountremainwithoffice"  ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ><input type="submit" value="Submit To Database" style="  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  cursor:pointer;"></td>

<td ><a href="More About Remote Employees.php?RemoteEmployeeID=<?php echo $remoteemployeeid ?>" style="
  font: 15px verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
">Back To Information</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In a situation where some of the `input` are empty or have an invalid value, `parseInt()` would return `NaN` and if any of the values from `PaymentsReceived1` to `PaymentsReceived12` is `NaN`, the sum would be `NaN`. You might want to check out the [isNan()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function to 'validate' your fields and then add them everytime `onchange()` is triggered.

Comment: To be constructively honest, this is some really sloppy code. This is the kind of code you're looking for when you google `bad code`.. Inline css styles, &nbsp instead of margin/padding, poorly written javascript etc. Your problem isn't how to add numbers, it's how to f&*$# code. Have some respect for what you do for a living.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to use as below,

```
var PaymentsReceived1 = Number(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived1.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply validation for all the fields as shown below.

```
var PaymentsReceived1 = isNaN(parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived1.value))?0:parseInt(document.TransactionForm.PaymentsReceived1.value);
```